# Apache camel ProducerTemplate asyncSendBody set JMS headers and properties

Tags: apache-camel, jms, spring-jms

Apache camel api has `ProducerTemplate.asyncSendBody(Endpoint endpoint, Object body)`.
I use the above to send messages to remote end point.

I want to know how can I set additional JMS properties and headers.

I see there is an api sendBodyAndHeader() which allows to do so. What is the equivalent of it in async api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `asyncRequestBodyAndHeader` method for sending the Camel Exchange asynchronously. The camel exchange will be sent in `Exchange.InOut` MEP.

Here's a test case that you can follow,

```
protected Object expectedBody = "<time>" + new Date() + "";
protected ActiveMQQueue replyQueue = new ActiveMQQueue("test.reply.queue");
protected String correlationID = "ABC-123";
protected String messageType = getClass().getName();

public void testForwardingAMessageAcrossJMSKeepingCustomJMSHeaders() throws Exception {
    MockEndpoint resultEndpoint = resolveMandatoryEndpoint("mock:result", MockEndpoint.class);
    resultEndpoint.expectedBodiesReceived(expectedBody);
    AssertionClause firstMessageExpectations = resultEndpoint.message(0);
    firstMessageExpectations.header("cheese").isEqualTo(123);        firstMessageExpectations.header("JMSReplyTo").isEqualTo(replyQueue);
    firstMessageExpectations.header("JMSCorrelationID").isEqualTo(correlationID);
    firstMessageExpectations.header("JMSType").isEqualTo(messageType);
    template.asyncRequestBodyAndHeader("activemq:test.a", expectedBody, "cheese", 123);
    resultEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
    List<Exchange> list = resultEndpoint.getReceivedExchanges();
    Exchange exchange = list.get(0);
    Object replyTo = exchange.getIn().getHeader("JMSReplyTo");
    LOG.info("Reply to is: " + replyTo);
    Destination destination = assertIsInstanceOf(Destination.class, replyTo);
    assertEquals("ReplyTo", replyQueue.toString(), destination.toString());
}
```